# Gimp on W10 install qmlexporter.py

Tags: plugins, gimp, export, qt

Need you help: I installed GIMP 2.10 and wanted to also use the plugin qmlexporter.py but it will not work, just by putting into the plugin folder.
Info states:https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-export-to-qml.html
there needs to be an edit in the design mode? What ??
Anyone has done this before and knows the way?? 
ThanX

Answer (score 0):

Editing a Python source file is dangerous if you are not used to it, Python is indentation sensitive and if you change the indent this leads to syntax errors. When this happens the plugin cannot execute its registration and doesn't appear in the menus. Furthermore the mentioned script uses tabs so that doesn't help; many editors will convert them at random to spaces, and for python, a tab is not the same as a series of spaces. So if you need to edit it use a real programmer's editor.

You can weed out the worst problems by running the script outside of Gimp in a command prompt (`python qmlexport.py`). If it complains about gimpfu, it could at least try to run it and you can then attempt to run it in Gimp. More hints [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows).

Btw, looking at the code it may have problems with Gimp 2.8 text layers that are more complex than text string+fonts.